# Batch Script robocopy exclude files but not in every folder

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am trying to copy contents of the `C:\`  drive from one computer to a new computer. I am only trying to copy any user files and not system files. This is my code so far.

```
@echo off
cls
@echo Type the old Computer Name
set /p asset=
@echo.
@echo What is the user's AIU?
set /p useraiu=

robocopy.exe \\%asset%\c$\ C:\ /S /Z /XJD /XJ /XA:SH /XA:T /XD "Dir1" "Dir2"  /XF *.dll *.log *.txt *.exe /log+:"\\server\path\%asset%-to-%computername%-Transfer.log" /NP /FP /V /TEE
```

I have the exclude Hidden Files, System Files and Temporary Files. I wanted to exclude .dll .log .txt .exe files from the ROOT of C but not from the folders being transferred.

Is it possible to only exculde the files from the Root of C but still transfer them if they exist in the folders?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xcopy`
It doesn't copy hidden files or system files. Add the `/e` parameter to copy empty folders. Add the `/c` parameter to ignore errors.

```
xcopy %src% %dest% /exclude:extlist.txt /s
```

**extlist.txt**

```
.dll\
.txt\
.exe\
.log\
.tmp\
```

**EDIT:**
Misunderstood your question. Didn't realize you were copying from a networked computer. Xcopy won't work then.